# date uses gettimeofday?

Tags: unix, date, freebsd, gettimeofday

When I do: date system call on freeBSD, does it internally use gettimeofday ?

Another que: how do I know where the code of "date" command sitting on the system?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can find the source for `date` in the [online SVN repository browser](http://svn.FreeBSD.org/viewvc/base/release/8.1.0/bin/date/date.c?view=markup).

The `date` command calls `time()` to get the current time.

Comment: Thanks Greg. Any commandline way of doing the same? Finding where source is sitting?

Comment: Thanks Greg, I am trying to see who can call gettimeofday? Any command you know which uses it?

Comment: @hari: On my system (with the FreeBSD source installed) the source file is at `/usr/src/bin/date/date.c`. I don't know of a command which specifically calls `gettimeofday()`, but the easiest way to get one is to write one and compile it.